# Norm of linear operator $T_n(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)D_n(x)dx$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be the Banach space of all continuous functions $f(x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$, provided by the uniform norm
$$
\|f\|=\max_{x\in [0,2\pi]}|f(x)|.
$$
Let 
$$
D_n(x)=\frac{\sin(n+\frac{1}{2})x}{\sin\frac{1}{2}x}
$$
Denote $Y$ by $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that the linear operator 
$$
T_n(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)D_n(x)dx
$$
from $X$ to $Y$ is bounded, and 
$$
\|T_n\|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|D_n(x)|dx.
$$

Comment: This does not have much to do with the specific value of $D_n$. This is still true for instance if you replace $D_n$ by a continuous function with finitely many $0$'s on $[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Of course the inequality $\leq $ is fairly obvious.

For the reverse inequality, let $x_k$ denote the finitely many $0$'s of $D_n$ in increasing order.

Approximate the function equal to the sign of $D_n$ with a continuous function whose graph is a succession of trapezoids whith bases $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ and whose bottom/top is $-1$ or $1$ depending on the sign of $D_n$ on $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$.

Then let the trapezoids tend to rectangles.

Comment: Great! I finally managed to help someone today!